# Find all files with text "example.html" and replace with "example.php" works only if no spaces are in file name

Tags: bash, unix, sed, grep, xargs

I have used the following to do a recursive find and replace within files, to update hrefs to point to a new page correctly:

```
#!/bin/bash
oldstring='features.html'
newstring='features.php'
grep -rl $oldstring public_html/ | xargs sed -i s@"$oldstring"@"$newstring"@g
```

It worked, except for a few files that had spaces in the name.

This isn't an issue, as the files with spaces in their names are backups/duplicates I created while testing new things. But I'd like to understand how I could properly pass paths with spaces to the sed command, in this query. Would anybody know how this could be corrected in this "one liner"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a *lazy* approach:

```
grep -rl $oldstring public_html/ | xargs -d'\n' sed -i "s@$oldstring@$newstring@g"
```

By default, `xargs` uses *whitespace* as the delimiter of arguments coming from the input. So for example if you have two files, `a b` and `c`, then it will execute the command:

```
sed -i 's/.../.../' a b c
```

By telling `xargs` explicitly to use newline as the delimiter with `-d '\n'` it will correctly handle `a b` as a single argument and quote it when running the command:

```
sed -i 's/.../.../' 'a b' c
```

I called a *lazy* approach, because as [@Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar) pointed out, this won't work if your files have newline characters in their names. If you need to take care of such cases, then use @Barmar's method with `find ... -print0` and `xargs -0 ...`

PS: I also changed `s@"$oldstring"@"$newstring"@g` to `"s@$oldstring@$newstring@g"`, which is equivalent, but more readable.

Comment: Explanation of my problem + simple fix based on my scenario, I like it! Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

```
find public_html/ -type f -exec grep -q "$oldstring" {} \; -print0 |
    xargs -0 sed -i '' s@"$oldstring"@"$newstring"@g
```

`find` will print all the filenames for which the `grep` command is successful. I use the `-print0` option to print them with the `NUL` character as the delimiter. This goes with the `-0` option to `xargs`, which treats `NUL` as the argument delimiter on its input, rather than breaking the input at whitespace.

Actually, you don't even need `grep` and `xargs`, just run `sed` from `find`:

```
find public_html/ -type f -exec sed -i '' s@"$oldstring"@"$newstring"@g {} +
```

Comment: Thanks, interesting to see a different approach to this.